# PhPUnit & Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: phpunit, bamboo

I am new here. How to configure PHP UNIT with Bamboo? Any Idea, I wasn't able to find out a proper documentation for this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you do little research about your problem and then post a more precise problem here.

Here you go:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Getting+started+with+PHP+and+Bamboo

ALSO
While setting Executable path you have to set path as: path/to/executable(phpunit folder).cmd
and not just:
path/to/executable(phpunit folder)

Comment: thanks for your quick response.
i will be more specific about my problems here.